# Android WebView Crash

Tags: android-fragments

I am showing ads in my application and getting following crash from most of the user's. Does anyone know about it?

signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
    eax 00000000  ebx b7677c74  ecx bf94b510  edx 00000000
    esi aa24b9a1  edi bf94b6a8
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000007b
    eip b75dc610  ebp b464e2b0  esp bf94b5d0  flags 00210282

backtrace:
    #00 pc 000e2610  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::getNativeCanvas(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+48)
    #01 pc 00001744  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
    #02 pc 001fa460  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
    #03 pc 001d0838  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
    #04 pc 001e4ae6  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
    #05 pc 0000b86c  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@app@webview@webview.apk@classes.dex

Comment: Haven't you checked the exceptions on your development machine?

Comment: I checked but did not find it in my code. I searched on internet about it find out that is error in libwebviewchromium.so. and it has been fixed in android 5.1 but what about lower than 5.1.

Comment: Then maybe you'll have to look for compatibility library for that API to work on API below 5.1

Comment: I don't know which will be fine? Can you suggest me few of them or may be one compatibility library.

Comment: Has anybody found a fix for this? or do we just wait for a chromium update? looks the google ads view is using a webview, and making the app crash...